# Static S3 site using AngularJS and database (simple online store)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, paypal, amazon-s3

This is more a question of possibility, more than the nitty-gritty of how.

I'd like to build a pseudo dynamic website that I can host entirely on a static server (assume AWS S3), is it possible to achieve the below on a static machine? The cost associated to a full Nginx/Apache server is too much for these small apps, hence looking for another option.

- Simple database of items, cost (can be updatable JSON/third-party DB)
- List above items on a simgle page
- Add items to cart
- Push items to payment system (PayPal/Stripe would work)
- Callback from payment system to mark item as sold

Basically a singe-layer online store, no storage of user details. Simply, see something, buy it, mark it as sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do it but I think your biggest problem is that without having any secure executable server code you'd be unable to secure your database passwords or auth tokens for PayPal/Stripe. So, anyone would be able to have direct unequivocal access to your database. This would make the app extremely liable to any attack. For example, I could go to your site, look at the javascript code to get credentials to your database, and then log in and drop all your tables. Suddenly, everything is gone. Additionally, I could access PayPal/Stripe to refund or even transfer dollars out to my account. Very dangerous to not have these variables secured, and the only way (that I know of) to secure variables like this would be to put them in a server side file that couldn't be read by users.

As to cost of a server, you can start up a t2.nano EC2 server and get it for $(.0065*24*365), less than $57 per year. You can get shared hosting from other sites for around this price as well. You don't need a ton of processing power, just authentication and database modification. And this way you can secure your database credentials and API tokens using environment variables.

Comment: Yes. Huge point that I'd completely forgotten about ... Thanks for that and agreed regarding the server, that way you still essentially have the static build but with the security alongside.